# Android camera intent resultcode sometimes wrong / Sony Experia Z

Tags: android, android-intent, camera

In my Android App I capture images with a camera intent. So I have a **listview** with different items, when clicking on an item an activity is shown where the user can take a picture. Below is the code for the camera intent:

```
    cameraintent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    cameraintent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_SCREEN_ORIENTATION,
            ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

    startActivityForResult(cameraintent, CAMERA_KEY);
```

and here the code for the `onActivityResult()`:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

        if (requestCode == CAMERA_KEY) {

            callDialog();

        } else {

                    }

    } else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {    

    }
}
```

With a couple of smartphones it works perfectly. But with Sony Experia Z sometimes the resultcode is 0 instaed of -1 for a successfull taken picture. I tested this with the logcat. The calling activity will be paused, and when getting back from camera intent it seems like the resultcode is lost. Maybe because the calling activity is in pause-state and onResume will be called after the onActivityResult-method? (See this also in logcat) So how could be guaranteed that i get the right resultcode back from camera intent?

Is this a lifecycle-issue? Because it seems like every second picture from one row item (after updating the data) this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

So i really don´t know if this is the one and only correct answer, but this fixed my issue. I changed the code to the following and now it works. Seems like some devices need to explicit name the filename etc.

```
            fileName = getCurrentTime() + "tmp.jpg";
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, fileName);
            mImageCaptureUri = getContentResolver().insert(
                    MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);

            Intent cameraintent = new Intent(
                    MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            cameraintent
                    .putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mImageCaptureUri);

            cameraintent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_SCREEN_ORIENTATION,
                    ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

            startActivityForResult(cameraintent, CAMERA_KEY);
```